# Google Chrome AutoCorrect?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check, dictionary, autocorrect

Is there a spell checker for Google Chrome that can automatically fix certain spelling errors?

Just like MS office has an [auto correct feature](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/about-automatic-corrections-HP005235065.aspx?CTT=3), is there anything similar for Google's Chrome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest version of Chrome (26.0.1410.43) has experimental support for auto-correct. To enable it, navigate to `chrome://flags`, scroll down until you see "Enable Automatic Spelling Correction" and press Enable. This feature is not yet supported on OS X.

Comment: hmm, I'm on version 27.0.1453.93 (fedora 18) and enabling this feature doesn't actually perform autocorrection, rather just mark the errors.

Comment: I noticed that too. When I wrote my answer I had just discovered the feature and hadn't really tried it yet. Lokking at [issue 7624](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7624), I saw just now that it is not yet implemented, although it is supposedly in the works.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no built-in support for autocorrect in Google Chrome. There is an open issue on the Chromium source code, [issue 7624](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7624) to be precise, that wants to add support for autocorrect. But this is not functional yet.

This leaves extensions as your only other option.

The two extensions related to autocorrect are *Textbox.io* and *ezAutoCorrect for GMail*. [Textbox.io](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/textboxio/mphmmffnkcbhbdjanibmkkanoikidpcb) works on Tumblr and Gmail. [ezAutoCorrect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ezautocorrect-for-gmail/fholdolknchpdbajhpdenookmikblmda) works on Gmail. If you're looking for auto correct for these sites, then congratulations! Otherwise, it appears you are out of luck for now.

Answer (score 2):

you have to go to settings --> show advance settings --> languages ---> languages and spell-checkers settings ---> check the Enable spell checking

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome (atleast the official build) comes with a built in spell checker. It is enabled by default as well. To enable it, if it's not, Goto Wrench -> Under the Hood - > Web Content -> Languages and spell-checker settings.

Comment: Is there also an auto correct feature?  Is there an add-on or extension that would add such a functionality?

Comment: Ahhh sorry I read auto correct and jumped to auto spell checker. As far as I can see there is not an extension for this. You can always check what extensions are available in the [Chrome Store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/)